# How can I start a process over SSH such that it will continue to run after I disconnect?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, process

XBMC occasionally crashes on my media server.  It's a pain to bring down the media server because I have to manually restart a number of services each time.  I'd like to be ablle to start XBMC from an SSH session and have it continue to run after I disconnect.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) will do what you are asking.