# Prevent process interruption when SSH connection fails

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to convert video with ffmpeg on a remote computer using SSH. Sometimes I get disconnected or get a server timeout and the process is interrupted. I've tried a bash script with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -threads 4 -c:v libx264 -crf 30 -preset slow output.mp4
```

but it's also interrupted when loose my connection in Putty.

Comment: Also: [How can I start a process over SSH such that it will continue to run after I disconnect?](http://superuser.com/questions/524586/how-can-i-start-a-process-over-ssh-such-that-it-will-continue-to-run-after-i-dis)

Answer (score 0):

Try screen. It's sort of a virtual terminal that runs your shell.
You start by typing "screen [enter]" then it starts your favorite shell (bash?).

Start your script and press "[CTRL]-A-D" then screen goes to background while still running your shell and tasks and you can log off.
Also works like this when connection drops.