# Run python script on server over ssh session in the background persistantly

Tags: linux, ssh, python, cuda

I got an account from my professor for our universities CUDA server for running some tests.

I am connecting via ssh over terminal. The thing is, as I close the terminal the server also seems to kill the running script. As I reconnect it has stopped.

No it is not possible that the script already terminated since those test runs should take a few hours even on those machine..

Can anybody help me here?

```
OS: Linux cuda01 3.13-1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.13.7-1 (2014-03-25) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Look at [GNU Screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/), [dtach](http://dtach.sourceforge.net/), or similar programs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I start a process over SSH such that it will continue to run after I disconnect?](http://superuser.com/questions/524586/how-can-i-start-a-process-over-ssh-such-that-it-will-continue-to-run-after-i-dis), [Prevent process interruption when SSH connection fails](http://superuser.com/questions/601307/prevent-process-interruption-when-ssh-connection-fails), [How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?](http://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior. When you close the terminal, the SSH session terminates, killing all child processes. You need to use something like `tmux` or `screen` on the server to fork and create a persistent shell, which will continue to run after the ssh session terminates, and can be reconnected to  when you log in again.

Comment: Exactly, simplest solution for you I think is `screen`. It's kind of a virtual terminal. Start it after logging in simply typing `screen`. Then "inside" of screen, start your script, and then you can detach from screen (`Ctrl+A,D`) and you are safe to log out. Next time when you login, type `screen -r`, it will reattach you to screen running in background.